# problem booting Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, boot

So I have a HP Microserver which was running 14.X Ubuntu for ages. Due to adding a new disk and a lack of space in root on the system, I decided to re-install from scratch using 16.04.

The current Kernel is 4.10.0-42-generic. Installation was successful. But since then, 9 times of 10 the system does not boot.

I get these errors:

```
ERST: failed to get log address
BERT: Can't request iomem region 0000000077fab650-0000000077fab6aa3
ata2.00: failed to enable AA
```

I've no idea what those mean. It then enters "emergency mode".

A bit of googling suggested a BIOS update to the Microserver which I did. Hasn't helped. I can usually get the system to boot with a combination of rebooting (multiple times) and/or power on/off. But this is not really acceptable for a reliable server. I don't think the issue is related to the new HDD (which is not the boot disk) as if I remove it, I still have the same issue.

Anyone able to point me to what these errors mean and how to fix the issue? I'm considering downgrading back to 14.X.

Comment: I did see one comment where the suggestion was made to boot with nomodeset - can you see if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying the version 16.04.3 LTS.

- Downgrading back to 14.04.1 LTS and 14.04.5 LTS is a working alternative. There is support until April 2019.
- An alternative is to try 16.04.**1** LTS, the first point release, which I use. There is support until April 2021. This version works well with various old hardware. See this link (and links from it) to find the relevant iso files,

  [How to select the version and flavour of Ubuntu](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13540865#post13540865)

Comment: Thanks sudodus for your response. Yes I am using 16.04.3 LTS.
I will give your suggestion of 16.04.1 a go first.